# How do I troubleshoot my leaking Grohe shower control?

Tags: shower

We recently remodeled our bathroom. Shower taken down to the studs, then rebuilt with new tile, etc., but we kept the Grohe temperature controls and control knobs for the 3 different shower heads. They were all disassembled and then reassembled when they finished.

Nothing leaked from the shower heads before the reno, but all of them do now. The contractor insists it’s not from anything they did, but did offer to replace the Grohe cartridges, anyway. That hasn’t helped, but they want to walk away from the job. They say the valves must be shot and it’s our problem. We just want to problem solve and try to make this better. It’s a slow leak - more like slow dripping, but all new.

I know Grohe parts are wicked complicated. If it’s not the cartridges, is there something that can happen when you reassemble the control knob that keeps the water from shutting off completely? It makes sense that this is possible.

I need someone to tell me what specific parts, or whatever, to ask them to check. I’m hoping asking the question in the right way will help get us to an answer.

Thanks in advance … !

Comment: Searching Google for `leaky grohe control troubleshooting` pulls up a bunch of 10 minute YouTube videos for me. I see a terrylove.com result in there. Have you checked this stuff out already?

Comment: Where exactly is the leaking coming from?

Comment: I’ll check out the videos - thanks. The leak is coming from the water line behind the shower head.